# Big dialog in iPad

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, modalviewcontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller

Does anybody know how to create control (or view) like this one

[image]

This question might be duplicated, any way I can't find an answer. Thank you.

Comment: It's called a modal view controller.

Comment: I think it's a regular view controller but displayed modally; which forces interaction of some sort instead of whatever's behind it.

Comment: And this modal view controller contains UITableView, enabled navigation bar and two buttons.

Comment: try to add UIView on current view and in this view add UITableView as subview

Comment: actually I need this one: [link](http://teleportex.ru/tm/testtest.png)

Comment: Any ideas about rounding corners and disabling background view ?

Comment: Please someone, does any body can say more?

Comment: @Dmitry: Please be patient.  Posting things like that does ***not*** encourage people to help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just implement a modal view controller. Read this - 
[Presenting View Controllers Modally](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/PresentingaViewController.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH14-SW18)